# Github inspection for non-standard file formats that can be read as txt

Tags: github, jade-platform

Using Github for version control of Jade databases. difference inspection for .scm does not work even though the files can be read as legible .txt files

Any way to tell github to treat a file as a .txt for diff checking or similar